# Python, CSV, & If Statements

Tags: python, csv, if-statement

I'm trying to write an if statement in python that will write to the csv file using the following code. I want the if statement to write to a cell in the CSV file. I want it to say "X is bigger than Y" or "Y is bigger than X".

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
x = int(raw_input())
y = int(raw_input())

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["Company Name","PE"])
f.writerow('[x+y, 
    if x > y:    
        print "X is bigger than y"
    if x < y:
        print "Y is bigger than x"
        ]')
```

When trying to correct it, I'm getting the following error:

```
"pe_ratio.py", line 8
f.writerow('[x+y,
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

This code resolved the problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
x = int(raw_input())
y = int(raw_input())

f = csv.writer(open("pe_ratio.csv", "w"))

if x > y:    
        f.writerow(["X is bigger than y"])
elif x < y:
        f.writerow(["Y is bigger than X"])
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with that code? Are you expecting the code within the quotes to somehow be executed?

Comment: You need to clarify your intent. Give us the output you want to see in your csv.

Comment: As a side note, opening a file in write mode and then never calling `close` on it is a good way to run into one of the most common duplicate questions on this site ("How come after I wrote to my file Python can't see anything in it?").

Comment: @abarnet
close("pe_ratio.csv")
is what I should put at the end right?

Comment: @RobB.: No. You have to hold on to the file object by storing it in a variable, and call its `close` method. Or, even better, just use a `with` statement whenever you use an `open` and you won't have to worry about `close` ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what makes you think you can do that?  you won't be able to reference your local variables x and y in a quoted string like that.  What execatly are you trying to accomplish?

If it is to simply print "X is bigger than y" or "Y is bigger than x" than this will do it:

```
if x > y:    
        f.writerow(["X is bigger than y"]
elseif x < y:
        f.writerow(["Y is bigger than X"]
```

Comment: I think if you make each of this `f.writerow([x+y, …` (and fix your capitalization to match his bizarre mixture) this will be exactly what he wants.

Comment: so
    f.writerow([x+y,
         if x > y:    
        f.writerow(["X is bigger than y"])
elif x < y:
        f.writerow(["Y is bigger than X"])

?

Comment: You forgot the closing parentheses.

Comment: @RobB.: No, because you can't put a statement in the middle of an expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can't evaluate code in the middle of a string. But you don't need to; you can evaluate code whose *value* is a string.

In your case, you're trying to evaluate an `if` statement, which doesn't *have* a value. You can fix this by either using a ternary `if` expression instead:

```
f.writerow([x+y, 
            "X is bigger than Y" if x > y else "Y is bigger than x"])
```

But notice that this doesn't handle the case of `x == y` properly; to do that, you need to nest one `if-else` expression inside another, which is even uglier than this already is.

A better solution is to use the `if` statement to drive `writerow` instead of the other way around:

```
if x > y:
    f.writerow([x+y, "X is bigger than y"])
elif x < y:
    f.writerow([x+y, "Y is bigger than x"])
```